# Django - Comparing DateTime Field with server time in template tags

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have an app with the following models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Event(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        description = models.TextField()
        event_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
        today_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

        class Meta:
                ordering = ('event_date',)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name
```

And in my templates I have a list of events and I want the page to check everytime it loads if the date of the event is in the past or in the future from today's date. So if tomorrow I access the page, the today's date it would be 12th April 2017 and so on. My template code is like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_title %}
Events
{% endblock %}
{% block content%}
<ul>
    {% for event in object_list %}
    {% if event.event_date <= event.today_date %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url " events:details" %}">
        {{ event.name }} | <span class="event_past">PAST EVENT</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url " events:details" %}">
        {{ event.name }} |
        </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Is that the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't create a `today_date` field. It will be set to the default value when the object is created, but it won't be automatically updated each day.

```
today_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

You could pass today's date as a variable from your view to the template context and do the comparison in the template, but it's better to keep the templates as simple as possible. A better approach would be to create a method on your model, e.g. `is_future_event`:

```
from datetime import date

class Event(models.Model):
    event_date = models.DateField()
    ...

    def is_future_event(self):
        return self.event_date > date.today()
```

Then in your template, you can call the method as follows:

```
{% for event in object_list %}
    {% if event.is_future_event %}
        Future event
    {% else %}
        Today or in the past
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It worked! thank you very much. I was not sure about how to do it inside the model, but I agree that the template has to be simple.