# django template 2 conditions in ifnotequal

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to know if there is a way to include 2 conditions in a **ifnotequal** django template tag, such that the the 2 conditions are checked simultaneously. For eg:

```
{% ifnotequal cond1 and cond2 %} 
    #do something here
{% endifnotequal %}
#This code doesn't seem to work though
```

Or is there any other way in which 2 conditions, each containing equality comparison between 2 fields of django model instances. My exact code in the template is:

```
{% ifnotequal user.profile.rollno applied_job.student_id %}
{% ifnotequal job.company applied_job.student_applied_job %}
```

I want the above 2 conditions to be simultaneously evaluated. Is there any other better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from django docs which says `{% ifnotequal %}` is deprecated, so don't use it.

> {% ifequal a b %} ... {% endifequal %} is an obsolete way to write {%
>   if a == b %} ... {% endif %}. Likewise, {% ifnotequal a b %} ... {%
>   endifnotequal %} is superseded by {% if a != b %} ... {% endif %}. The
>   ifequal and ifnotequal tags will be deprecated in a future release.

Instead you can use `{% if a != b %}`

In your case:

```
{% if user.profile.rollno != applied_job.student_id and job.company != applied_job.student_applied_job %} 
    <!-- Write your markup here-->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. But I want to evaluate both the conditions simultaneously. How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe you could implement the logic in the model, I leave you my question similar to yours one and you could take the same approach [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342136/django-comparing-datetime-field-with-server-time-in-template-tags)